How to add nvm to terminal VSCode forever
I added zsh to my terminal in VSCode and installed nvm.
But every time I open the terminal in vs code, it must re-run
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

If not, it will throw an error:

nvm not found and node not found

how to fix it :((

Do you have that line in your .zshrc ?

Why don't you source it in one of your zsh startup files, for instance ~/.zshenv ?

The NVM install script should edit your .zshrc to add the following:
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

This will source the required file needed for NVM to work properly.

If you installed NVM by hand, you'll need to place that into your .zshrc (or .bashrc) yourself.
For more information, please see the installing and updating guide.

In my .zshrc I have following lines:
export PATH="~/.nvm/versions/node/v22.3.0/bin:$PATH"
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

This works for me on Ubuntu Linux.

t sounds like the issue is that your terminal isn't automatically sourcing your NVM (Node Version Manager) configuration when you open it. This typically happens because the startup files for your shell are not correctly sourcing the necessary NVM script.
As a workaraound, add the following line in your ~/.bashrc file
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

After adding the above line, you'll need to restart your terminal.
